# Register to magento database from other places

Tags: magento

How can i register new user from another other place. I would like to use single database.

I have another website and I would like to use register class from magento because I would like have one database for two websites.

Answer (score 1):

You could register a new customer from your external site via [Magento SOAP API](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/customer/customer.create.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can create **multi website** from magneto installation. That will use single database only. Have a look at the magento wiki for [multisite configuration](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-multi-site-multi-domain-setup).

Comment: thank you. I think that need PHP code / class for register users, because I would like use like below:

- I will have 4 parameters: name, surname, email, password

4 paramters -> script -> response (ok, error response in JSON)

Comment: Are you taking about web service. Do you want to register user by web service.